# CSS positioning driving me nuts

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, positioning

I have multiple images that take up the entire screen and auto resize (positioned absolutely and some JavaScript) however for the life of me I can not get content to be placed UNDER that `div`. I put the images in a `div` container and that `div` is positioned relative to every other one. The `div` with the necessary content is relative as well. The images are absolute within a relative `div`. Can someone take a look at my code and let me know exactly whats going on? I just can't figure it out, and after all the research I have done I do not see why it isn't working. Thank You! Below is the external style sheet and the HTML. I believe the issue is within the actual HTML for `div` cycler (where the images are), because I embedded the style within the HTML for that `div` and the content at least does fall under the top `div`s (defined in style sheet).

```html
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

#mainbody
 { margin:0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; overflow: scroll;}

#topnav.mainnav {
    background-color: rgb(27, 89, 127);
    height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 3000px;
    max-height: 45px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -45px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    /*box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 2px #333;*/
        display: table; position: fixed;z-index: 4;
    }

#linktable.listlink { height: inherit; width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; position: relative; display: table; text-align: center;}

ul {list-style-type: none; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; background-color: rgb(27, 89, 127); height: 45px; width: 760px;}

li {float: left;}

li a.other { display: block; padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 14px; padding-right: 14px; margin: 0; border: 0;
 height: 45px; color: #FFF; text-decoration: none; font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; font-weight: 500;
}

li a:hover { background-color: rgb(131, 139, 146);  -o-transition:.3s;
  -ms-transition:.3s;
  -moz-transition:.3s;
  -webkit-transition:.3s;
  /* ...and now for the proper property */
  transition:.3s }

li a.current { background-color: rgb(238, 237, 240); color: rgb(27, 89, 127);  padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 14px; padding-right:14px; margin: 0; border: 0; display: block;  text-decoration: none;
 height: 45px; font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; font-weight: 500;}

#namebar.topname {
    background-color: rgb(238, 237, 240);
    height: 123px;
    min-width: 760px;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 123px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(131, 139, 146);
    margin-top: 45px;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0px;
}

img.dfrelogo { margin-top: 0px; width: 359px; height: 123px}

img.firstimagehome {width: 100%; max-width: 5472px;min-width:760px; height: auto; box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px #333333; text-align: center;}

#homefirstimage {margin-top: 0px; text-align: center;}
```

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Welcome to Dean Flint Real Estate!</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/main.css" id="main" media="screen and (min-width: 800px)" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/mini.css" id="mini" media="screen and (max-width: 799px)"  type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
#cycler{ position:relative; width: 100%; max-width: 5472px;min-width: 359px; float:left; display: table}
#cycler img{position:absolute;z-index:1;width: 100%; max-width: 5472px;min-width: 359px; height: auto;; text-align: center;box-shadow: 3px 2px 6px  #333333; float:left}
#cycler img.active{z-index:3; width: 100%; max-width: 5472px;min-width: 359px; height: auto;text-align: center;opacity: 100; float:left}
</style>
</head>
<body id="mainbody">
<nav>
<div id="topnav" class="mainnav">
<div id="linktable" class="listlink">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html" class="current">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="agents.html" class="other">AGENTS</a></li>
<li><a href="featured.html" class="other">FEATURED LISTINGS</a></li>
<li><a href="current.html" class="other">CURRENT LISTINGS</a></li>
<li><a href="aboutus.html" class="other">ABOUT US</a></li>
<li><a href="contactus.html" class="other">CONTACT US</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
<header>
<div id="namebar" class="topname"><img src="images/temp/dfrelogo.jpg" class="dfrelogo" /></div>
</header>
<section>
<div id="cycler">
<img src="images/front_page/frontimage.jpg" />
<img src="images/front_page/frontimage2.jpg" class="active" />
<img src="images/front_page/frontimage3.jpg" />
</div>
</section><br />
<footer>
<div style="position: relative;" ><p>This text should go UNDER the above pictures</p></div>
</footer>
<script type="text/javascript">
function cycleImages(){
      var $active = $('#cycler .active');
      var $next = ($active.next().length > 0) ? $active.next() : $('#cycler img:first');
      $next.css('z-index',2);//move the next image up the pile
      $active.fadeOut(1500,function(){//fade out the top image
          $active.css('z-index',1).show().removeClass('active');//reset the z-index and unhide the image
          $next.css('z-index',3).addClass('active');//make the next image the top one
      });
    }

$(document).ready(function(){
// run every 4s
setInterval('cycleImages()', 6000);
})</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you needed this, '#cycler img{position:absolute}'.

If you remove the absolute position of the 'img' tag in the cycler div, the text will go down as you needed.

```
#cycler img{z-index:1;width: 100%; max-width: 5472px;min-width: 359px; height: auto;; text-align: center;box-shadow: 3px 2px 6px  #333333; float:left}
```

This will do.

To know about absolute position this is a good short answer.

position: absolute;
This tells the browser that whatever is going to be positioned should be removed from the normal flow of the document and will be placed in an exact location on the page. It won't affect how the elements before it or after it in the HTML are positioned on the Web page however it will be subject to it's parents' positioning unless you override it.

Comment: Hey mbstone, did you try this?